# Update href text value dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are href links on the page, its text is not complete. for example page is showing link text as "`link1`" however the correct text should be like "`link1 - Module33`". Both page and actual texts starts with same text (in this example both will starts with "`link1`").
I am getting actual text from JSON object from java session and comparing. If JSON text starts with page text (that means JSON text "`link1 - Module33`" startsWith "`link1`" (page text), then update "`link1`" to "`link1 - Module33`".

Page has below code to show the links

```
<div class="display_links">
 <ul id="accounts_links_container">
  <li id="accounts_mb_2_id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linksmall" 
    id="accounts_mb_2_a"> link1 </a></li>
  <li id="accounts_mb_11_id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linksmall" 
   id="accounts_mb_11_a"> link2 </a></li>
    .
    .
    .
// more links
 </ul>
</div>
```

Note : li id is not static its different for each page text, however ul id is static.

I am reading correct & full link text from JSON object (from java session) as below

```
var sessionValue = <%= json %>; // taken from String array
```

and reading page text as below :-

```
$('.display_links li').each(function() { pageValue.push($(this).text()) });
```

sessionValue has correct updated text and pageValue has partial texts. I am comparing using below code

```
for(var s=0; s<pageValue.length; s++) {                
             var pageLen = $.trim(pageValue[s]).length;               
            for(var w=0; w<sessionValue.length; w++) {
                   var sesstionLen = $.trim(sessionValue[w]).length;                   
                  var newV = sessionValue[w].substring(0, pageLen);
                  if($.trim(newV)==$.trim(pageValue[s])){
                  **// UPDATING VALUES AS BELOW** 
                   pageValue[s]=sessionValue[w];             
                  }
             }
         }
```

I am trying to update page value text to session value text as `pageValue[s]=sessionValue[w];` (in above code) but its not actually updating the values. Sorry for the poor comparing text logic.
Please help, how to update it dynamically in the loop after comparing to make sure I am updating the correct link text.

Comment: the partial text you are referring is the value of the anchor tag? `link1` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's cleaner to just select the elements you care about (in this case the anchor tags) and then use built-in functionality to compare rather than reimplementing a startsWith function.

```js
var sessionValue = ['link1 - Module33', 'link2 - foobar'];

$('.display_links li a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text().trim();
  sessionValue.forEach(function(sessionValue) {
    if (sessionValue.startsWith(text)) {
      $this.text(sessionValue);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display_links">
 <ul id="accounts_links_container">
  <li id="accounts_mb_2_id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linksmall" id="accounts_mb_2_a"> link1 </a></li>
  <li id="accounts_mb_11_id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linksmall" id="accounts_mb_11_a"> link2 </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @jconder It worked perfectly for me, also getting the link on updated text

Comment: I observed this code is working fine on chrome and firefox but not on IE, any tips for this to work in IE as well?

Comment: startsWith isn't supported by IE, but you can include a polyfill to make it work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill

Answer (score 2):

`pageValue[s]=sessionValue[w];` just updates the array; it has no effect whatsoever on the `li`'s text.

If you want to update the `li`'s text, you need to do that in your `each`. Here's an example doing that, and taking a slightly more efficient approach to the comparison:

```
$('.display_links li a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $.trim($this.text());
    var textLen = text.length;
    for (var w = 0; w < sessionValue.length; ++w) {
        var sessionText = $.trim(sessionValue[w]);
        if (sessionText.substring(0, textLen) == text) {
            text = sessionText;
            $this.text(text);
            break; // Found it, so we stop
        }
    }
    pageValue.push(text); // If you want it for something
});
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder After trying I am getting below code without link on it    <div class="display_links">
  
 <div class="display_links">
  <ul id="accounts_links_container"><li id="accounts_mb_14_id">link1 - Module33</li></ul>
 </div>       However I am expecting to get below with link <ul id="accounts_links_container"><li id="accounts_mb_14_id"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linksmall" id="accounts_mb_14_a">link1 - Module33</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: @Rakesh: The selector for the `each` should be `'.display_links li a'`, not just `'.display_links li'`. Fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$(this).text()` is a primitive string, not a reference to the textNode of the element. It doesn't matter if you update `pageValue`, because it is not related to the original element.

Instead of pushing the strings to an array to process, you can stay inside the `$.each()` loop and still have access to the elements, which is needed to update the text. Something like this:

```
 $('.display_links li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var liText = $.trim($li.text());
    var liLen = liText.length;  

    for(var w = 0; w < sessionValue.length; w++) {
        var sessionLen = $.trim(sessionValue[w]).length;                   
        var newV = sessionValue[w].substring(0, liLen);

        if ($.trim(newV) === liText) {
            **// UPDATING VALUES AS BELOW** 
            $li.text(sessionValue[w]);             
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am a noob and thought I would take a shot at this.
>   Here is my approach although the sessionValue array is a bit foggy to me. Is the length undetermined?

I declared var's outside of the loop for better performance so they are not declared over and over.

*Iterate through elements passing each value through Compare function and returning the correct value and update immediately after all conditions are satisfied.*

```
var i = 0;

$('.display_links li a').each(function(i) {

  $(this).text(Compare($(this).text(), sessionValue[i]));
  i++;

});

var Compare;
var update;

  Compare = function(val1, val2) {
  // Check if val1 does not equal val2 and see if val2 exists(both must be true) then update.
  if(!val1 === val2 || val2) {
        update = val2
  }
  return update;
}
```